# Results on intersections of compact sets in non-metrizable spaces

Tags: general-topology

We know that if $X$ is a Hausdorff topological space and $C_0 \supseteq C_1 \supseteq ...$ are nested, non-empty compact sets, then $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} C_i \neq \emptyset$, this is [Cantor's Intersection Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem). However, this gives us no information about the "size" of $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} C_i$. For instance, we could take $X= \mathbb{R}$ and take $C_i= [1- \frac{1}{i+1}, 1+ \frac{1}{1+i}]$ and get $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} C_i= \left\{1 \right\}$, but we could also give an expression for $C_i$ such that $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} C_i$ yields the [Cantor Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) and hence is uncountable. I am interested in statements of the following form:

"For a non-metrizable topological space $X$ and compact, non-empty $C_i \subseteq X$, if $C_i$ each have Property (1), then $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} C_i$ contains exactly one element."

I emphasize "non-metrizable" here because there are analogous statements for metrizable spaces and the specific spaces I'm looking at are never metrizable. Does anyone know of any theorems of the above form?

Also, obviously if $|C_i|=1$ for each $i$ then the statement holds, so anything other than that would be better.

Comment: A sufficient condition would be that for every $x\in X$ except some unique $x_0\in X$, there exists an $i\in\mathbb{N}$ depending on $x$ such that $x\notin C_i$.

Comment: I doubt that you tell what size the set is using topology alone in full generality unless the space is Hausdorff. Without that property, you can have multiple topologically indistinguishable points (by that I mean they are in exactly the same open sets). In a Hausdorff space, you might be able to get a result like you want.

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect. It is true for Hausdorff spaces, because compact subsets of a Hausdorff space are closed. In the co-finite topology on $N$ (where  $S\subsetneqq N$ is closed iff $S$ is finite), every subset is compact, but $\cap_{n\in N}(N$   \ $ \{n\})=\emptyset.$

Comment: I'll take your word for it, the linked Wikipedia article makes no mention of the Hausdorff property though, that's why I didn't mention it. Wolfram Alpha does however, in fact it restricts Cantor's theorem to to just the reals.

Comment: @user254665 also, I'm taking $N$ to be the natural numbers here, but how does $N$ \ $ \left\{n \right\}$ satisfy the descending inclusion condition?

Comment: It doesn't.  Let $C_n=\cap_{j\leq n}(N$  \   $\{n\})$.

Answer (score -2):

We have the follow related theorems:

Compact Subspace of a Hausdorff space is Closed: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Subspace_of_Hausdorff_Space_is_Closed

Closed Subset of Compact Space is Compact https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closed_Subspace_of_Compact_Space_is_Compact

Not a complete answer, but you can probably used these to help you with this question.